# Robotux - Macros disappearing

Tags: 14.04

Robotux is a simple macro recorder with GUI for Ubuntu/Linux. After every restart Robotux all saved macros are disappearing. Maybe someone knows how to fix this bug?

Look at the screenshot:

[image]
Ubuntu 14.04 x64 3.13.0-49-generic

Comment: I can not test, because I have no desire to pay for it :)

Comment: oh sure, I thought someone already has it )

Comment: But, good luck. I already have upvoted.

Comment: Please add your edit as a answer and accept it - this is not forum :)

Answer (score 0):

Install gsettings-desktop-schemas

```
sudo apt-get install gsettings-desktop-schemas
```

Compile schema

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /opt/robotux/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

I had this problem recently and had to solve it myself. It's a really great application IMHO, but there's not much support about it. LOL

TIP: If you want to disappear the notifications, comment this line of code

```
self.current_notification.show()
```

on /opt/robotux/robotux/MainClass.py

Hope this helps!